# Hidden android libraries

Tags: java, android, hidden, libraries

In a project, I have one library (myLibs for instance) who use an other one (toolsLibs). 
In fact, toolsLibs is a library who I didn't write and I can't change some methods on it (I have just a .jar file).

Actually, I would like to know if it's possible to use methods of toolsLibs in myLibs, but hidden toolsLibs for a user of myLibs (someone who just import myLibs in his project)? (that mean I want have methods of toolsLibs who can only use on myLibs project).

I didn't find nothing about that so I don't know if it's possible, any one can help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, I would like to know if it's possible to use methods of toolsLibs in myLibs, but hidden toolsLibs for a user of myLibs?

Only by getting rid of toolsLibs entirely, folding its contents into myLibs and removing any `public` classes, methods, etc. Even then, somebody using reflection could get at that stuff.

Comment: the problem is that toolsLibs is an "unwritable" librairies. I just can use what it's contain.

Comment: @ThisIsALow: I have no idea what you mean by "unwritable" in this context, sorry. If toolsLibs is in a developer's project, they can use whatever public API is offered by toolsLibs.

Comment: toolsLibs is a librairie who I didn't write, and I can't do some modification on it.Actually, toolsLibs is a library of a partner and my aim is to use it in my library, but avoid that developpers who will use my library can see that there is toolsLibs in myLibs. Do you know what I mean? (sorry for my quite bad english)

Comment: @ThisIsALow: "avoid that developpers who will use my library can see that there is toolsLibs in myLibs" -- that is not possible, sorry.